# Covariance with a columns

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization

If I have a numpy array X with `X.shape=(m,n)` and a second column vector y with `y.shape=(m,1)`, how can I calculate the covariance of each column of X with y wihtout using a for loop? I expect the result to be of shape `(m,1)` or `(1,m)`.

Comment: Have you looked at np.cov() function?  Seems to work with matrices in correlation with vectors.  Look at, http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html

Comment: Yes but I am working with text data, and np.cov would calculate the covariance between columns in the X matrix, which has 100000 columns. this would be very slow.

Comment: Shouldn't the output be of size `1xn` or `nx1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the output is meant to be of shape `(1,n)` i.e. a scalar each for `covariance` operation for each column of `A` with `B` and thus for `n` columns ending up with `n` such scalars, you can use two approaches here that use `covariance formula`.

**Approach #1: With Broadcasting**

```
np.sum((A - A.mean(0))*(B - B.mean(0)),0)/B.size
```

**Approach #2: With Matrix-multiplication**

```
np.dot((B - B.mean(0)).T,(A - A.mean(0)))/B.size
```