# Efficient computation of covariance with streaming returns data in numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'm designing a python plugin for my firm's portfolio simulator which receives daily return data for all instruments in the portfolio as it steps through the simulations of each day.

My module should update its covariance matrix on the cross-section of instruments every day. In order to do this, my approach so far has been:

1. Buffer the returns data inside module in a numpy array(ret: shape = (num_days(D), num_instrs(N)) with indices mapped to a ring buffer(data for date di goes into di%ret.shape[0]).
2. populate the covariance matrix by fetching returns array in to a 1-d array with np.take(since it's a ring buffer) and call np.cov pairwise.

This implementation has the following inefficiencies:

1. Each day, I have to call np.take() to wrap-around the ring buffer(ndarray) and thereby, incur significant copy cost. If I don't do this, I have option of using np.roll() but that too involves an array copy as well.
2. The covariance computations are carried out on these temporary intermediate arrays pairwise(O(N^2 * D)). Doesn't scale well with N(order of millions) or D(250-1000 days).

At my firm, we're working on a fairly large-cross section(N ~= 1E6 - 1E7). I need my implementation to be scalable, memory-efficient and fast.

Can you suggest any improvements to the current scheme which may benefit this task?

Comment: The `covariance` part could be vectorized. Here's one related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447457/covariance-with-a-columns

Comment: Maybe you should consider something like [TensorFlow](https://www.google.pt/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjc28rGq7bJAhVJ2hoKHdXnDcMQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftensorflow.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNG2kVII66seRFchHAaQLCezUj9Hig&bvm=bv.108194040,d.ZWU)

Comment: Would an algorithm that iteratively updates the covariance matrix based on new 'data vectors' solve your problem?

Comment: I agree with @mathewgunther: if an online covariance matrix computation would solve your pb, this link could be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498612/fast-incremental-update-of-the-mean-and-covariance-in-python