# Fast incremental update of the mean and covariance in Python

Tags: python, numpy, normal-distribution

I have a Python script where I need to frequently update the mean and co-variance matrix. What I am currently doing is that each time I get a new data point $x$ (a vector), I recompute the mean and covariance as follows:

```
data.append(x) # My `data` is just a list of lists of floats (i.e., x is a list of floats)
self.mean = np.mean( data, axis=0) # self.mean is a list representing the center of data
self.cov = np.cov( data, rowvar=0)
```

The problem is that is not fast enough for me. Is there anyway to be more efficient by incrementally updating `mean` and `cov` without re-computing them based on all the `data` ?

Computing mean incrementally should be easy and I can figure it out. My main problem is how to update the covariance matrix `self.cov`.

Comment: Read [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance) and use the online algorithm, both for the variance and covariance. Stay away from the suggestions below to keep track of the sums of squares, as they can be numerically unstable.

Comment: This paper describes a quick method of updating mean and other moments https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.04923

Comment: @Jaime Nah, it converges only after hundreds of iterations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out that we can easily do that using the mdp library
http://mdp-toolkit.sourceforge.net/api/mdp.utils.CovarianceMatrix-class.html

Comment: I would love to see how you applied this.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it by keeping track of the sum and sum of squares.

In the `__init__`:

```
self.sumx = 0
self.sumx2 = 0
```

And then in the append:

```
data.append(x)
self.sumx += x
self.sumx2 += x * x[:,np,newaxis]

self.mean = sumx / len(data)
self.cov = (self.sumx2 - self.mean * self.mean[:,np,newaxis])  / len(data)
```

Noting the `[:,np.newaxis]` broadcasting to find the produce of every pair of elements

Answer (score 0):

For mean calculation, you could store the mean of N data before, suppose it's called "before_mean", and when new data x comes, new mean of these N+1 data will be simply calculated like before:

```
new_mean = float(before_mean * N + x) / (N + 1)
```

so you don't need to recalculate before data.

For cov, I don't think there is simply way to solve that, and I am not sure about your data input, as cov always used with list other than number.

Just for curious, I think you don't need to care about this if dataset not that large, as it's O(N)

Hope it helps~

============ update ===========

```
import numpy as np
import random

data = []
means = []
for m in range(3):
    sample_data = random.sample(range(10), 5)
    means.append(np.mean(sample_data))
    data.append(sample_data)

# calculate origin cov
origin_cov = np.cov(data)
print origin_cov

# new data
x = random.sample(range(10), 5)
mean_x = np.mean(x)
var_x = np.var(x)
new_line_cov = []
new_cov = np.empty([len(data)+1, len(data)+1])
for idx, sample_data in enumerate(data):
    mul_x_sample = 0
    for (elem_x, elem_sample) in zip(x, sample_data):
            mul_x_sample += (elem_x * elem_sample)
    mul_x_sample = mul_x_sample / len(x)
    cov_x_sample = mul_x_sample - mean_x * means[idx]
    new_cov[idx] = np.append(origin_cov[idx],cov_x_sample)
    new_line_cov.append(cov_x_sample)
new_line_cov.append(var_x)
new_cov[len(data)] = np.array(new_line_cov)

print new_cov
```

the output result like below:

origin

```
[[ 9.7   2.7  -4.05]
 [ 2.7   3.7  -3.05]
 [-4.05 -3.05  5.7 ]]
```

new

```
[[ 9.7   2.7  -4.05  0.56]
 [ 2.7   3.7  -3.05  1.56]
 [-4.05 -3.05  5.7   0.36]
 [ 0.56  1.56  0.36  8.56]]
```

Comment: The mean is easy to compute incrementally. My problem was mainly how to update the covariance matrix. My `data` is just a list of lists of floats.

Comment: @eLearner , I don't think it's supported in numpy directly, but it could be checked manually, please check my updated answer code, thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a variance (only the diagonal of the covariance matrix) it is simple. You need to also keep the sum of squares for your data. Recall that the formula for variance is: Var(x)=E[x^2]-(E[x])^2). So each step you are calculating your regular mean, and the mean of the squares sum.

This can be generalized for multivariate variables for a full covariance matrix. Have a look [here](http://rebcabin.github.io/blog/2013/01/22/covariance-matrices/).